# FileSystemWatcher fired my event on new file but my UI updated twice

Tags: c#, winforms

I built an application that listens to folder using `FileSystemWatcher` and when a new file is created a timer starts for a few seconds to ensure the whole file is in the folder. Then the start event to my main ui thread runs adding this file into my ListView.

The new file created successfully is added to my `ListView` but my problem is that after the first one is added, the second one is added twice and the next file is added 4 times etc...

my listener class:

```
public class FileListener
{
    private static string _fileToAdd;
    public event EventHandler _newFileEventHandler;
    private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public void startListener(string directoryPath)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directoryPath);
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        watcher.Filter = "*.pcap";
        watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    }

    void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {            
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myEvent);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _fileToAdd = e.FullPath;
    }

    private void myEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _newFileEventHandler(_fileToAdd, EventArgs.Empty);
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

my event who handle with the new file:

```
void listener_newFileEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file = sender as string;
    addFileToListFiew(file);

}
```

and the function that add the file into my `ListView`

```
public void addFileToListFiew(string file)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        lvFiles.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
        { 
            file, "Waiting"
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: You keep adding event handlers to the timer.  Only add the myEvent handler once.

Comment: i added _timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(myEvent) after _timer.Stop() and it's seems to work fine now but when i am move to my folder several files in the same time, one file of them appears several times

Comment: There are great answers here, but there is one thing you need to watch for - double events. You need a guard for this situation. Look at the details section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can unsubscribe from the previous event subscription using the following:
//You may also need a global boolean variable to keep track of whether or not the watcher currently exists... Although, I am not sure if that is the best resolution for the problem...
watcher.Created -= watcher_Created;

//...

if(eventSubscriptionExists)
{
    //if already subscribed, either do nothing, or re-subscribe

    //unsubscribe from event
    watcher.Created -= watcher_Created;
    //subscribe to event
    watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
}
else
{
    //if not already subscribed to event, start listening for it...
     watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
}
```

Comment: where should i put watcher.Created -= watcher_Created ?

Comment: I would add the above logic to the FileListener class, and call into main for the value of the boolean variable

Comment: where should i put the if - else statement ?

Comment: After reading comments from the above, it appears as if your original problem has been solved, and now you have a different issue?

Comment: yes, now i have new issue, i try to add 2 new files and one of them added twice, the second did not added

Comment: If you are adding a new file to a directory, you may receive two different "FileSystemEvents", the "Created" Event, and the "Changed" event.  In the filesystemwatcher event, e.FullPath is the property that contains the filename that was changed; e.ChangeType is the property that contains the type of event that is occurring.  You can use this to help understand why the event is firing twice.  The OS first creates an empty file, then fills it up with the content.  Also, you may not be receiving events for Both of the files due to a timing issue.  So your test is comprised of only two files?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged.aspx

Comment: usually i don't think more than one file will create at same time but of course i want to check several cases, and i subscribe only for create and not Changed, can i unsubscribe from OnChange ?